# Use root name as property in entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, entity

I'm kind of new in jackson subject and I did not find any answer which would help me resolve the problem.

For a sec let's assume that I have this class:

```
    public class Airport {
        private String name;
        private String code;
        ...
    }
```

My json looks like this:

```
 "XXX": {
       "name": "SomeName",
  }
```

I would like to force Jackson to put `XXX` (root of tree) into `code` property from the class. Standard way I use to create objects from JSON is using `treeToValue`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String airports = "above Json";
JsonNode airportsTree = mapper.readTree(airports.toString());
Airport airport = mapper.treeToValue(airportsTree, Airport.class);
```

However when I enable `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` I'm getting

> JsonMappingException: Root name 'XXX' does not match expected ('JsonNode') for type [simple type, class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode]

Answer (score 0):

You need put `root name` hint for jackson

```
@JsonRootName(value = "XXX")
public class Airport {
    private String name;
    private String code;
    ...
}
```

When you enable `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` it must works

Comment: But mate the problem is that this value is different for each record:
`XXX`,
`XYZ`,
`ABZ`

Comment: I mean that `XXX` value (which sis root name) should go to `name` part of the class.